# Execution time of a ksh script

Tags: bash, unix, time, execution

I want to know execution time of the ksh script, without editing or running the script.

any command to get time taken by the script to execute?

Comment: "without editing or **running the script**" really?

Comment: yes I need without editing or running the script

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.  First you mention "...execution time...", then you mention "...without running the script..." and then you again mention "time...script to execute..." .  I am going to assume that you just want to know how long it takes for a script to execute.  Please clarify if I am incorrect.  Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible for a rather significant number of reasons, including but not by any means limited to - how fast is your CPU, how busy is it, what does the script do, how might it fail if certain assumptions aren't met, how does the input given to the script change the behavior of the script, .......

Answer (score 1):

You can try time command as below ;

```
root@host:/tmp:>cat test.ksh 
#!/bin/ksh
echo started
sleep 3
echo finished
root@host:/tmp:>date; time ksh test.ksh  ; date
Tue Jul 19 14:36:43 EEST 2016
started
finished

real    0m3.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
Tue Jul 19 14:36:46 EEST 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `time` command with your script:

```
time for x in 1 2 3 4; do ./your_script.ksh; done

real    1m20.085s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.025s
```

or you can use the `SECONDS` parameter available in `ksh` within your script:

```
begin_time=$SECONDS
your_shell_code_here
end_time=$SECONDS
elapsed_time=$((end_time - begin_time))
```

Refer to `printf` to format the output contained in `elapsed_time`.